How to subclass vtkColorTransferFunction?
I want to implement custom color calculation for color lookup table. I've subclassed vtkColorTransferFunction and overrided GetColor and MapValue functions. But the color has no change, whether I use original vtkColorTransferFunction or my subclass. Moreover, the functions I've overrided wasn't called by VTK core. How can I implement custom color calculation?
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import (
    vtkActor,
    vtkDataSetMapper,
    vtkRenderWindow,
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor,
    vtkRenderer
)
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import (
    vtkColorTransferFunction
)
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonDataModel import (
    VTK_QUAD,
    vtkUnstructuredGrid,
)
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore import vtkPoints
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
from typing import Tuple, MutableSequence
import math
import numpy as np

class LogarithmicColorTransferFunction(vtkColorTransferFunction):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.originalMin = 0
        self.originalMax = 1

    def SetOriginalRange(self, min, max):
        self.originalMin = min
        self.originalMax = max

    def MapValue(self, v:float):
        print(v) # Just dummy print, but was never executed
        return super().MapValue(v)
    
    def GetBlueValue(self, x:float):
        print(x) # Just dummy print, but was never executed
        return super().GetBlueValue(x)

    def GetColor(self, x:float) -> Tuple[float, float, float]:
        print(x) # Never executed
        log = math.log
        exp = math.exp
        a = self.originalMin
        b = self.originalMax
        y = -((log(a)-log(b*x-a*x+a))/(log(b)-log(a)))
        # y = (exp(x*(log(b)-log(a))+log(a))-a) / (b-a)
        return super().GetColor(y)
    
    def GetColor(self, x:float, rgb:MutableSequence[float]) -> None:
        print(x) # Never executed
        c = self.GetColor(x)
        rgb[:] = c

def main():
    ctf = LogarithmicColorTransferFunction()
    ctf.SetColorSpaceToRGB()
    ctf.SetScaleToLinear()
    ctf.SetNanColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    table = np.array([
        [0, 0.01, 0.043, 1],
        [0.2, 0.641, 0.164, 0.725],
        [0.3, 0.988, 0.051, 0.11],
        [0.5, 1, 0.975, 0.5],
        [0.8, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]
    ])

    for point in table:
        ctf.AddRGBPoint(*point)
    ctf.SetOriginalRange(1, 5)

    points = vtkPoints()
    ugrid = vtkUnstructuredGrid()
    data = np.array([[0, 0, 0,],
                     [10, 0, 0],
                     [10, 10, 0],
                     [0, 10, 0]])
    points.SetData(dsa.numpyTovtkDataArray(data))
    quad = [0,1,2,3]
    ugrid.InsertNextCell(VTK_QUAD, 4, quad)
    ugrid.SetPoints(points)
    c = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])/3
    ugrid.GetPointData().SetScalars(dsa.numpyTovtkDataArray(c))

    mapper = vtkDataSetMapper()
    mapper.SetInputData(ugrid)
    mapper.SetLookupTable(ctf)

    actor = vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)

    renderer = vtkRenderer()
    renderWindow = vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
    renderWindowInteractor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

    renderer.AddActor(actor)
    renderWindow.Render()
    renderWindowInteractor.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

